# C++ - Why is my cout code displaying decimals inconsistently?

Tags: c++, cout, decimal-point

I'm working on an app that needs to print an array through cout on one line, and show 2 decimal places.  Currently, my code prints the first two items with 2 decimals, then switches to 1.

Here is the code:

```
cout << "  Inches ";
    cout << showpoint << setprecision(2) << right;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << precipitation[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
```

And here is the output:

`Inches  0.72 0.89  2.0  3.0  4.8  4.2  2.8  3.8  2.7  2.1  1.6  1.0`

Can someone please tell me why this change is precision is occurring and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What types are these variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use "fixed" mode.  In default floating-point mode, precision() sets the number of significant figures to display.  In "fixed" mode, it sets the number of places after the decimal.  Case in point:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float pi = 3.14;
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << pi << endl;
    cout << fixed << pi << endl;
}
```

Gives the output:

```
3.1
3.14
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add cout << fixed before output statements in addition to showpoint and setprecision, you will get a consistent formatting for all outputs.

See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double precipitation[12] = { .72, .89, 2, 3, 4.8, 4.2, 2.8, 3.8, 2.7, 2.1, 1.6, 1 };
    cout << "  Inches ";
    cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2) << right;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << precipitation[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the output will be as bellow:

```
Inches  0.72 0.89 2.00 3.00 4.80 4.20 2.80 3.80 2.70 2.10 1.60 1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I was troubled with this problem too. You need to use 'fixed' to do this.

Refer to this link:
[C++ setprecision(2) printing one decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618912/c-setprecision2-printing-one-decimal)